# How to get specific rows from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to apologize in advance if the question is stupid, but how can I get a few specific rows from  a dataframe?

For example, I am given a dataframe with n rows and I want to print out the first and the last 4 rows.
I can certainly do something like this

`df.iloc[[1,2,3,4,n-3,n-2,n-1,n],:]`

But maybe there is more simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 2):

[pandas.DataFrame.iloc()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) can accepts a list or array of integers, which you already use in your example.

> I want to print out the first and the last 4 rows
>
> I can certainly do something like this
>
> `df.iloc[[1,2,3,4,n-3,n-2,n-1,n],:]`

Besides this, you can use `range()` to generate the list like:

```py
df.iloc[list(range(0, 4))+list(range(len(df.index)-4, len(df.index))), :]
```

You can generate a index list to simplify the procedure

```py
index = list(range(0, len(df.index)))
df.iloc[index[:4]+index[-4:], :]
```

[pandas.DataFrame.head()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) and [pandas.DataFrame.tail()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) can retrieve rows from up and bottom quickly. With the help of [pandas.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), you can combine the result of these two method:

```py
pd.concat([df.head(4), df.tail(4)]))
```

`iloc()` can also accept a slice object with ints, e.g. `1:7`. This can have the same effect with `head()` and `tail()`

- `head(4)` equals `iloc[:4]`
- `tail(4)` equals `iloc[-4:]`

```py
pd.concat([df.iloc[:4], df.iloc[-4:]])
```